# Proving $((a\bmod n) (b\bmod n))\bmod n = ab\bmod n $

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove a property of modular arithmetic, namely: 
$$[(a\bmod n)\times (b\bmod n)]\bmod n = ab\bmod n.$$
I have the basis and hypothesis steps down, but I am having trouble with the hypothesis step:

**Proof**
Let $P(n)$ be the predicate 
$$P(n): [(a \bmod n) \times (b \bmod n)] \bmod n = a  b \bmod n.$$

**Basis step:**
$$\begin{align*}
\ [(a \bmod 1) \times (b \bmod 1)] \bmod 1  &=  (a  b) \bmod 1\\  
\ [( 0 )\times ( 0 )] \bmod 1  &=  (a  b) \bmod 1  &&\text{(any \number is }0\text{ modulo }1\text{)}\\
                     0 \bmod 1 &=  (a  b) \bmod 1\\
                            0      &=      0            &&\text{(true for }n=1\text{)}
\end{align*}$$

**Hypothesis step**

*(Assume that $P(n)$ is true for some $n=k$):*
$$[(a \bmod k) \times (b \bmod k)] \bmod k = (a  b) \bmod k$$

**Induction Step**

*(Prove that $P(n)$ is true for some $n = k + 1$)*
$$\begin{align*}
\ [(a \bmod (k+1)) \times (b \bmod (k+1))] \bmod (k+1)  &= (a  b) \bmod (k+1)\\ 
\ [(a \bmod k) + 1 \times (b \bmod k)  + 1] \bmod (k+1)  &= (a  b) \bmod (k+1)\\
\end{align*}$$

I get to here then I can't figure out how to cancel out the 1's on the left hand side.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It is incorrect that $a\bmod (k+1) = a\bmod k + 1$. For example, take $a=4$, $k=7$. Then $a\bmod k+1 = 4$, but $a\bmod k + 1 = 5$.

Comment: Do you have to do this by induction? It can be done directly fairly easily, and I honestly do not see how to do it by induction on the modulus; it is not straightforward to see how to relate remainders modulo $k$ with remainders modulo $k+1$; they can be very different. In fact, for any pair of positive integers $r$ and $s$, $0\leq r,s\lt k$, you can find an integer $a$ such that $a\bmod k = r$ and $a\bmod (k+1) = s$.

Comment: @ArturoMagidin The assignment only said prove, but induction happens to be the only method of proving that I know.

Comment: If you **really** need to do it by induction, fix $a$, and do an induction on $b$ (assumed non-negative, you can pick up the negatives easily once you have the positives).

Comment: @Hunter: Surely you know how to prove things directly? For example, do you prove that if $a|b$ and $b|c$, then $a|c$ by inductin? Or using the definition of "divides"? Use the definition here.

Comment: How would I go about proving this directly then?

Comment: Address $\: n\leq 0 \:$ separately. $\:\:\:$ For $\: 0\lt n \:$, $\:$ express $a$ and $b$ as multiples of $n$ plus members of $\{0,1,2,3,...,n+(-1)\}$. $\:\:\:$ Multiply, expand, and notice that adding multiples of $n$ does not change the result. $\;\;\;\;$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $c = a\bmod n$, true iff $a = jn +c$ for some integer $j$.  Similarly  $d = b\bmod n$ iff $b = kn +d$ for some integer $k$.

So,

$ab\bmod n = [(jn+c) \times (kn+d)]  \bmod n $

$= [(jkn+jd+kc)n + c \times d] \bmod n $

$ = c \times d \bmod n $

$=  [(a\bmod n)\times (b\bmod n)]\bmod n$,

which is what you wanted to prove.

Comment: the last step. How prove `a * b mod n` = '[(a mod n) * (b mod n)] mod n`?

Comment: @Algebra My identities start at $ab\bmod n$  and finish at $=  [(a\bmod n)\times (b\bmod n)]\bmod n$.  What do you think is missing?

Answer (score 4):

Note that by the Chinese Remainder Theorem, for any $k\gt 0$, and for any integers $a$ and $b$, there exists an integer $x$ such that
$x\bmod k = a\bmod k$ and $x\bmod (k+1) = b\bmod (k+1)$. That is: the remainders of $x$ modulo $k$ and modulo $k+1$ are completely unrelated. So I do not see how you are going to be able to leverage "knowing" the result modulo $k$ into a proof of the result modulo $k+1$, unless you simply prove it directly modulo $k+1$.

So it is really simpler to show that the result holds modulo $n$ directly, for any $n\gt 0$.

Remember that $x\bmod n = r$ if and only if $0\leq r\lt n$ *and* $x-r$ is a multiple of $n$.

So first show that $ab - (a\bmod n)(b\bmod n)$ is a multiple of $n$. For example, if $a\bmod n = r$ and $b\bmod n = s$, then $a-r$ and $b-s$ are both multiples of $n$; then $(a-r)b$ is a multiple of $n$, and $r(b-s)$ is a multiple of $n$, so...

Comment: Thank you this was a good start for me.