# How to prove that $(a-b) \mod N = a \mod N + ((-b) \mod N)$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, arithmetic

I've gone through the similar post [Modulo of a negative number](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/519845/103816) . But that post is not about proof and I'm asking for the proof in general.

This question is another [follow up question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1377221/why-do-remainders-show-cyclic-pattern#comment2805043_1377241) of my [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1377221/103816). The question is how can we prove that $(a-b) \mod N = a \mod N + ((-b) \mod N)$.

Comment: What is the exact definition of $ x \bmod N$ that you are working with?

Comment: What do you mean my $a \bmod N$? Is your $=$ supposed to mean the two expressions are equal as integers? [In arithmetic modulo $N$ we would normally treat two integers which differ by a multiple of $N$ as being 'the same' or equivalent]

Comment: @mixedmath  By $x \mod N$ I mean the remainder leftover when $x$ is divided by $N$. $x$ can be negative and the remainder must be less than $N$ and must be positive.

Comment: @MarkBennet My `=` means they are numerically equal. Please do not confuse it with $\equiv$.

Comment: If you use mod to mean remainder, as is common in Computer Science but not in Number Theory, then the assertion is false. Let $a=2$ and $b=1$, with say $N=7$. Then the left side is $1$ and the right side is $8$.

Comment: Then your formula should be: $(a-b)\bmod N=(a\bmod N+( -b)\bmod N)\bmod N$.

Comment: @user103816 Then, as others have said, the assertion cannot be proved. Whatever definition you choose - e.g. least non-negative residue, or residue of least absolute value (positive for tie break) - you will be able to find values for which the two expressions are not equal.

Comment: @MarkBennet Then how is $6\mod7=(-1)\mod7$? And is the formula posed [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/519845/103816) incorrect?

Comment: @user103816 You have that $6-(-1)=7$ - any two numbers whose difference is divisible by $7$ are equivalent modulo $7$ - that is one way of defining the concept.

Comment: @MarkBennet How can we prove that any two numbers(positive or negative) which are divisible by $x$ are equivalent modulo $x$?

Comment: @MarkBennet Isn't $(( -b)\bmod N)\bmod N=(-b)\bmod N$?

Answer (score 2):

The comments are getting complicated.

The main point of working modulo $N$ is to make multiples of $N$ irrelevant, so we define $a\equiv b \bmod N$ if and only if $N\mid a-b$ or equivalently if there is an integer $r$ with $a=b+rN$.

The relation $\equiv$ defined in this way is easily seen to be an equivalence relation which divides the integers $\mathbb Z$ into $N$ equivalence classes.

It is easily seen that $(a+kN)+(b+rN)=a+b+(k+r)N$

and $(a+kN)(b+rN)=ab+(ar+bk+krN)N$

So addition and multiplication respect equivalence.

One way of doing arithmetic modulo $N$ is to choose a representative element of each equivalence class. Often this is the remainder on division by $N$, giving representatives $0, 1, 2 \dots N-1$ (I'll call this the standard set). Sometimes it is more convenient to choose the residues of least absolute value (with $N/2$ taken for the relevant class if $N$ is even).

As regards negative numbers we have $-b\equiv N-b\equiv 2N-b \dots$ and this will eventually give a positive residue.

Though it makes sense to choose a set of representatives of the classes - for example, the standard set - and do our arithmetic using these, it is easy to see that these cannot be closed under addition or multiplication* (take the residue of greatest absolute value and add it to itself, or square it). The result may have to be adjusted by a multiple of $N$ to give the required residue. The same is true of subtraction.

You can either try to work over the integers and have to adjust your results by multiples of $N$ to get equality, or you can work with equivalences throughout.

If in doubt go back to the definition and work over $\mathbb Z$ using arbitrary multiples of $N$ - the language of equivalence does the same job whilst simplifying the expressions and the arithmetic.

---

*For multiplication there is an exception: the residues $\{0,1\}$ are closed under multiplication modulo $2$

Comment: Why is $-b\equiv N-b\equiv 2N-b \dots$?

Comment: @user103816 because $-b-(kN-b)=-kN$ is divisible by $N$ and that is the definition of equivalence.

Comment: I didn't know that the definition is also true for negative numbers?

Answer (score 1):

We would like to prove that:

$(a-b) \text{ mod } N = (a \text{ mod } N + (-b) \text{ mod } N) \text{ mod }N$

and

$(a-b) \text{ mod } N = (a \text{ mod } N -b \text{ mod } N) \text{ mod }N$

Let us first start proving that $c=(a+b) \text{ mod } N = (a \text{ mod } N + b \text{ mod } N) \text{ mod }N$

This means, in other words, that:

(1) $ a+b = c+Nf :  0<c<N\rightarrow c=(a+b) \text{ mod } N $

(2) $a = r+Nk :  0<r<N\rightarrow r=a \text{ mod } N $

(3) $b = r'+Nk' : 0<r'<N \rightarrow r'=b \text{ mod } N $

Summing (2) and (3) we get:

(4) $a+b = r+r'+N(k+k') = r+r'+Nt$

This is very similar to (1), however, not equal since $0<(r+r')<2N$

Let us take the mod of $r+r'$ and insert (4):

$r+r'= \gamma +No$

$a+b-N(k+k')=\gamma + No \rightarrow $

$a+b =\gamma + N(k+k'+o)=\gamma+Nh :   0<\gamma<N$ , which is eq (1).

Therefore, $(a+b) \text{ mod } N = (a \text{ mod } N + b \text{ mod } N) \text{ mod }N$

Making $b=-b$

$(a-b) \text{ mod } N = (a \text{ mod } N + (-b) \text{ mod } N) \text{ mod }N$

Since $(-a) \text{ mod } N= N-a \text{ mod } N$,

$(a-b) \text{ mod } N = (a \text{ mod } N +N- b \text{ mod } N) \text{ mod }N$

And then, finally

$(a-b) \text{ mod } N = (a \text{ mod } N - b \text{ mod } N) \text{ mod }N$